# C++ structure: more members, MUCH slower member access time?

Tags: c++

I have a linked list of structures. Lets say I insert x million nodes into the linked list,
then I iterate trough all nodes to find a given value.

The strange thing is (for me at least), if I have a structure like this:

```
struct node
    {
    int a;
    node *nxt;
    };
```

Then I can iterate trough the list and check the value of a ten times faster compared to when I have another member in the struct, like this:

```
struct node_complex
   {
   int a;
   string b;
   node_complex *nxt;
   };
```

I also tried it with C style strings (char array), the result was the same: ***just because I had another member (string), the whole iteration (+ value check) was 10 times slower***, even if I did not even touched that member ever! Now, I do not know how the internals of structures work, but it looks like a high price to pay...

What is the catch?

**Edit**:
I am a beginner and this is the first time I use pointers, so chances are, the mistake is on my part. I will post the code ASAP (not being at home now).

**Update**:
I checked the values again, and I know see a much smaller difference: 2x instead of 10x.
It is much more reasonable for sure.

While it is certainly possible it was the case yesterday too and I was just so freaking tired last night I could not divide two numbers, I have just made more tests and the results are mind blowing.

The times for a the same number of nodes is:

1. One int and a pointer the time to iterate trough is 0.101
2. One int and a string: 0.196
3. One int and 2 strings: 0.274
4. One int and 3 strings: 0.147 (!!!)
5. For two ints it is: 0.107

Look what happens when there is more than two strings in the structure! It gets faster! Did somebody drop LSD into my coffee? No! I do not drink coffee.

It is way too fckd up for my brain at the mo' so I think I will just figure it out on my own instead of draining public resources here at SO.

(Ad: I do not think my profiling class is buggy, and anyway I can see the time difference with my own eyes).

Anyhow, thanks for the help.
Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure it's the pure iteration time you measure, not including the creation time of your list elements? Creating a string is much more costly than creating an int. Have you tried two `int` fields?

Comment: Please post the code for your linked list structure

Comment: @Péter Török: I am sure. Creation time is not included in the measurement. I have not tried with two int fields yet, but will.

Comment: It's possible you're seeing some sort of processor cache effect, where adding one more member to the struct meant that your test data no longer completely fitted in L2 cache.

Comment: Could we see the code that iterates through the list?

Comment: 1) Why are you implementing your own list? This is surely more bug-prone than just using `std::list`, and probably not as efficient. 2) Why are you using a list at all? Lists are arguably the worse container you can possibly use. They have virtually no cache coherency, require frequent use of dynamic allocation, and even their benefits (constant time insertions/deletions) are seriously outweighed by the previous problems. 3) So use a `std::vector` or `std::deque` and enjoy better cache usage. Like always, performance problems are typically just bad design choices.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how performance of your program relates to the actual size taken up by b. In this case it would thus be interesting to see how performance is as a function of the length of the string b.

Comment: @GMan: I am trying to learn the ins and outs of pointers and I tought implementing some linked list stuff would help.
@Mike Seymour: I will post the code, but I am at work atm.

Comment: +1 from me, by the way, for both trying to understand the language you're working in, and the performance characteristics of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I must be related to memory access. You speak of a million linked elements. With just an int and a pointer in the node, it takes 8 bytes (assuming 32 bits pointers). This takes up 8 MB memory, which is around the size of cache memory sizes.

When you add other members, you increase the overall size of your data. It does not fit anymore entirely in the cache memory. You revert to plain memory accesses that are much slower.

Comment: Also, the larger noted might use more TLB entries, possibly triggering a bit of TLB thrashing.

Comment: I don't think the total cache size is important, since the data is so scattered already that pretty much every node will be a cache miss when it is first accessed, and since it isn't used again later, it makes no difference that it is evicted from the cache again later on. Most likely, cache misses are occurring and account for at least part of the slowdown, but not because of the total cache size

Answer (score 5):

This may also be caused because during the iteration you *may* create a copy of your structures. That is:

```
node* pHead;
// ...

for (node* p = pHead; p; p = p->nxt)
{
    node myNode = *p; // here you create a copy!
    // ...
}
```

Copying a simple structure very fast. But the member you've added is a `string`, which is a complex object. Copying it is a relatively complex operation, with heap access.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the issue is that your larger struct no longer fits inside a single cache line.

As I recall, mainstream CPUs typically use a cache line of 32 bytes. This means that data is read into the cache in chunks of 32 bytes at a time, and if you move past these 32 bytes, a second memory fetch is required.

Looking at your struct, it starts with an `int`, accounting for 4 bytes (usually), and then `std::string` (I assume, even though the namespace isn't specified), which in my standard library implementation (from VS2010) takes up 28 bytes, which gives us 32 bytes total. Which means that the initial `int` and the the `next` pointer will be placed in different cache lines, using twice as much cache space, and requiring twice as many memory accesses if both members are accessed during iteration.

If *only* the pointer is accessed, this shouldn't make a difference, though, as only the second cache line then has to be retrieved from memory.

If you always access the `int` and the pointer, and the string is required less often, reordering the members may help:

```
struct node_complex
{
   int a;
   node_complex *nxt;
   string b;
};
```

In this case, the `next` pointer and the `int` are located next to each others, on the same cache line, so they can be read without requiring additional memory reads. But then you incur the additional cost once you need to read the `string`.

Of course, it's also possible that your benchmarking code includes creation of the nodes, or (intentional or otherwise) copies being created of the nodes, which would obviously also affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a spacialist at all, but the "cache miss" problem rings in my head while reading your problem.

When you had a member, as it makes the size of the structure get bigger, it also might cache misses when going throught the linked list (that is naturally cache-unfriendly if you don't have nodes allocated in one bloc and not far from each other in memory).

I can't find another explaination.

However, we don't have the creation and the loop provided so it's still hard to guess if you're not just having code that don't perform the list exploration in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution would be a linked list of pointers to your object. It may make things more complicated (unless you use smart pointers, ect.) but it *may* increase search time.